# Anyone can give me an advice to use QuillJS in CLJS or other text editor for dashboard using Clojure?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Can anyone give me advice to use QuillJS in CLJS or other text editors for a dashboard using Clojure?

Here is my problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: In the image you link to, you seem to have written "quill", but I guess that you mean "quil".

Comment: It depends on your context. What frontend / view library are you using? Did you check out quil on https://cljsjs.github.io/ ? There are prepackaged versions ready for consumption in CLJS project.